# Breadcrumbs page [id] nextjs dynamic page

Tags: next.js, breadcrumbs

1 I need to get the name to paste for the id in the breadcrumb section
2 can't be more optimized when I already get the data in the dynamic page but also have to get 1 more time for this breadcrumb
The way I came up with is to turn off the breadcrumb in the dynamic page
and self-attach

I am using component layout cover page

```
const getDefaultTextGenerator = useCallback((subpath: string) => {
    return {
        product: "Product",
    }[subpath] || subpath;
}, [])

const getTextGenerator = async (param: string, query: ParsedUrlQuery) => {
    const fetcher = (url: RequestInfo) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())

    return { 
        "product_id":  await fetcher(`/api/product/${query.product_id}`).name,
    }[param];
}

return (
    <>
        <Head>
            <title>NextShop2</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
            <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <Navbar />
        <main>
            <Container maxW={'container.xl'}>
                <Breadcrumb
                    getDefaultTextGenerator={getDefaultTextGenerator}
                    getTextGenerator={getTextGenerator} />
            </Container>
            {children}
        </main>
        <Footer />
    </>
)
```

not working

```
`"product_id":  await fetcher(`/api/product/${query.product_id}`).name,`
```

and dynamic page /product/[product_id].tsx

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
     const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST}/api/product`)
     const products = await res.json()
     const paths = products.result.map((product: any) => ({
         params: { product_id: product._id },
     }))
     return { paths, fallback: false }}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }: any) {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST}/api/product/${params.product_id}`)
    const product = await res.json()
    return { props: { product } }}
```

component BreadcrumbCustom

```
const _defaultGetTextGenerator = (param: string, query: ParsedUrlQuery) => null;
const _defaultGetDefaultTextGenerator = (path: string) => path;
const generatePathParts = (pathStr: any) => {
    const pathWithoutQuery = pathStr.split("?")[0];
    return pathWithoutQuery.split("/").filter((v: []) => v.length > 0);}

function BreadcrumbCustom({getTextGenerator = _defaultGetTextGenerator, getDefaultTextGenerator = _defaultGetDefaultTextGenerator})

const router = useRouter();
const breadcrumbs = React.useMemo(function generateBreadcrumbs() {
    const asPathNestedRoutes = generatePathParts(router.asPath);
    const pathnameNestedRoutes = generatePathParts(router.pathname);

    const crumblist = asPathNestedRoutes.map((subpath: string, idx: number) => {
        const param = pathnameNestedRoutes[idx].replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

        const href = "/" + asPathNestedRoutes.slice(0, idx + 1).join("/");
        return {
            href,
            textGenerator: getTextGenerator(param, router.query),
            text: getDefaultTextGenerator(subpath)
        };
    })

    return [...crumblist];
}, [router.asPath, router.pathname, router.query, getTextGenerator, getDefaultTextGenerator]);

if (router.asPath == '/') return <></>
return (
    <Breadcrumb pt='6'>
        <BreadcrumbItem>
            <NextLink href='/'>
                <BreadcrumbLink ><Icon as={BsHouse} /></BreadcrumbLink>
            </NextLink>

        </BreadcrumbItem>
        {breadcrumbs.map((crumb, idx) => (
            <Crumb {...crumb} key={idx} last={idx === breadcrumbs.length - 1} />
        ))}
    </Breadcrumb>
);
```

function Crumb { text: defaultText, textGenerator, href, last = false }: { text: string, textGenerator: any, href: string, last: boolean }

```
const [text, setText] = React.useState(defaultText);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!Boolean(textGenerator)) { return; }
    const finalText = textGenerator;
    setText(finalText);
}, [textGenerator]);

if (last) {
    return (<BreadcrumbItem isCurrentPage={true}>
        <NextLink href={href}>
            <BreadcrumbLink>{text}</BreadcrumbLink>
        </NextLink>
    </BreadcrumbItem>)
}

return (
    <BreadcrumbItem >
        <NextLink href={href}>
            <BreadcrumbLink>{text}</BreadcrumbLink>
        </NextLink>
    </BreadcrumbItem>
);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.